# copy element of first array to second array with pointer

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

**i want to copy element of first array to the second array with pointer
 but after compiling i get message that is A problem caused the program to stop working correctly.windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is avilable**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int arr[30],arr1[30];
  int n,i;
  int *p,*q;
  p=arr;
  q=arr1;
  printf("Enter the no. of elements of array:-\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter the array element of 1st array:-\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    scanf("%d",p+i);

  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    q=(int*)*(p+i);
    q++;
  }
  printf("elements of array 1=");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("%d , ",*(p+i));
  }
  printf("\nelements of array 2=");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("%d , ",*(q+i));
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    printf("%d , ",arr1[i]);
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    q=(int*)*(p+i);
    q++;
  }
```

To

```
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
    q[i]=p[i];
  }
```

As of now you are treating `int` as `int *` and assigning it to pointer leading to undefined behaviour.

Also `*(p+i)` is same as `p[i]` and `(p+i)` is same as `&p[i]`. But latter ones are more readable.